# capybara how to get operating system info

Tags: selenium, operating-system, capybara

I need to get the operating system info to handle OS related tasks. I tried to get it via `page.driver.browser` but it doesn't return os info. It could be in `header` but there is no function header.

How can I get OS information by `page` object?

```
irb#1(main):016:0> page.driver
=> #<Capybara::Selenium::Driver:0x007f84a35c0858 @app=nil, @browser=#<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x1a664c8c1eb09ac0 browser=:firefox>, @exit_status=nil, @frame_handles={}, @options={:browser=>:firefox}>
irb#1(main):017:0>
irb#1(main):018:0* page.driver.browser
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x1a664c8c1eb09ac0 browser=:firefox>
irb#1(main):019:0>
irb#1(main):020:0* page.driver.browser.header
NoMethodError: undefined method `header' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x007f84a34cb9e8>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using selenium you should be able to look at

```
page.driver.browser.capabilities.platform
```

That will only work for the selenium driver though, not the other available capybara drivers

Comment: Anyone got a link to the documentation on `capabilities.platform`? I've confirmed it works, but looking for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In your ruby console you can run

```
Config::CONFIG["host_os"]
```

Or

```
RUBY_PLATFORM
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
2.0.0-p598 :001 > Config::CONFIG["host_os"]
(irb):1:in `irb_binding': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(irb):1:in `irb_binding': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
 => "linux-gnu" 


2.0.0-p598 :001 > RUBY_PLATFORM
 => "x86_64-linux"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: please read carefully the question... I think he wants to achieve the info through his capybara/selenium code, not in console.

Comment: he wants to know the OS info so that he can perform the tasks dependent on OS to perform his selenium operations. If he is writing ruby code, he can run this command get the output and proceed with his selenium code!

Comment: how can I reach it via `page` object?